# Tengo una tabla en DataTables funciona al iniciar pero si cambio de pantalla y vuelvo ya no funciona

Tags: datatables

Buenas tardes y de antemano muchas gracias por sus respuesta.

Soy novato en estos caminos de la programación y tengo un problema que no logro resolver. Tengo una tabla con DataTables funciona perfectamente cuando se ingresa a la cuenta, pero cuando cambio de pantalla a otro apartado del menú y vuelvo me sale el error:

```
     jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).DataTable is not a function TypeError: 
     $(...).DataTable is not a function
     $(...).DataTable is not a function
           at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```

Sin embargo si presionó Ctrol+mayus+R para la carga de manera forzada se soluciona y vuelve a funcionar perfecto.

El problema ocurre cuando trabajo en pantalla incognito y en otros computadores, ya que en mi equipo funciona perfectamente.

Tengo construido el sitio en Joomla y trabajo con Gantry.

La tabla donde se muestra es:

```
<table class="table" id="table_productos_servicios">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Imagen</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
    </table>
```

La función de ajax es:

```
var tableProductos = $('#table_productos_servicios').DataTable({       

            "ajax": {
            method:"POST",
            url:  URLPRODUCTOS,
            data: datos,  
            
            },
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "pageLength": 10,
            "columns": [
                { mData: 'nombre'},
                { mData: 'precio'},
                { mData: 'image'},                      
                { mData: 'acciones'}
              
            ],
            "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sSearch": "",
                "searchPlaceholder": "Buscar...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast": "Último",
                    "sNext": "Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                },
                "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
            },            
            "paging": true,
            "ordering": false,
            "info": false,
            "searching": true
        });
```

Y el PHP de donde viene la informacion:

```
$data [] = array(
                    "nombre" => $nombre,
                    "precio" => formatoEuro($precio),
                    "image"  => $imageProducto,                   
                    "acciones" => $actionButton
                );
$res = array(
                "sEcho" => 1,
                "iTotalRecords" => count($data),
                "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data),
                "aaData" => $data
                );

                echo json_encode($res);
```

Como comento en si la información se muestra pero solo una vez, cuando se cambia de pantalla y se vuelve ya genera el error "Es como si perdiera la conexión con la CDN de DataTable." Ya que solo funciona de nuevo si fuerzo el reinicio.

Comment: cuál es el código con el que cargas el datatable? como llenas esos datos? no nos estás mostrando nada...

Answer (score 0):

¡¡¡¡Resuelto el problema!!!! lo que hice fue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Estaba aquí dentro "tableProductos.dataTable" y lo saque de la función de inicio del jquery, lo coloque antes de iniciar el jquery y listo se solvento// carga sin problema aun 
    cuando cambio de pagina
});
```

Gracias a las personas que respondieron... Seguimos aprendiendo...

Comment: Considera [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta, ya que el usuario "Comunidad" [se encarga de revivir la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215/qu%c3%a9-sucede-con-las-preguntas-que-tienen-respuestas-validas-pero-no-son-marcadas/1452#1452) cada cierto tiempo.